# javascript attributes clarification

Tags: javascript, html

please help,
why all 4 sections are linking to section 4 please?
i added the equivalent IDs and data attributes but they all link to section 4

```
//select the sections list
const sectionsList = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
//select the ul
const navBar = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
//transform the sections list to an array
const sectionsListArr = Array.from(sectionsList);

//iterate through the sections list
for (let i = 1; i <= sectionsListArr.length; i++) {

   let text = "Section " + [i];
   let li = document.createElement('li');
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   let newText = document.createTextNode(text);

//append the li items to the ul
   link.appendChild(newText);
   li.appendChild(link);
   navBar.appendChild(li);

//link li items to their corresponding section
  const dataAttribute1 = link.getAttribute('Section 1');
  const dataAttribute2 = link.getAttribute('Section 2');
  const dataAttribute3 = link.getAttribute('Section 3');
  const dataAttribute4 = link.getAttribute('Section 4');
  const setAttribute1 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section1');
  const setAttribute2 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section2');
  const setAttribute3 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section3');
  const setAttribute4 = link.setAttribute('href', '#section4');

}
```

Comment: You're setting the same attribute 4 times on each link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this. Each `.section` will need an unique ID, though.

```
const navBar = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".section")).forEach((section, i) => {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = `#${section.id}`;
  link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Section ${i + 1}`));
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(link);
  navBar.appendChild(li);
});
```